# Having a error when i connect python with mysql database and unable to solve it

Tags: python, mysql

```
        import mysql.connector

        conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
                           user="root",
                           password="mypassword",
                           database="mydatabase"
                           )
        conn = mysql.connector.connect('tablename.frm')

        conn.close()
```

## When i run this program, the following error occurs:-

```
       Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\Real Project MYSQL.py", line 3, in <module>
       conn = mysql.connector.connect('PAYSLIP.db')
       File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 265, in connect
       return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
       File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 64, in __init__
       super(MySQLConnection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
       >>>
```

#I am unable to solve this error.

Comment: I think that 'table_name.db' is a sqlite3 db file.  You need information of username, password, etc when connecting to a MySQL database.

Comment: I have also tried with this extension, 'table_name.frm'.

Comment: You cannot connect the MySQL table file directly.  You need to connect the database via socket or named socket with information of `username`, `password`, `host` (via socket) and `database` name, etc.

Comment: Because that's not how you use that library. You must use keyword arguments, not positional ones. And you need to provide host, password, etc, not the table name. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html Read the documentation.

Comment: import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
                               user="root",
                               password="darshan",
                               database="PAYSLIP"
                               )
conn = mysql.connector.connect('Payslip.db')

conn.close()

I have done it. but the same error occurs

Comment: You should remove the line `mysql.connector.connect('Payslip.db')`.